# Using grep to find specific version number of a package in composer.lock file?

Tags: grep, silverstripe

I am wanting to `grep` the version number of a package that I have pulled in via composer from my `composer.lock` file.

I have extracted the object that contains the version number to make it easy to see on StackOverflow. However there are multiple other packages being pulled in by composer as well which all have their own version number of course. I need to the version number of the `silverstripe/framework` which is `3.5.3` as per below.

How can I do this via the command line using `grep`? Also open to other solutions if there is a better/easier way.

**composer.lock**

```
{
            "name": "silverstripe/framework",
            "version": "3.5.3",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework.git",
                "reference": "a2580456bda9ff513cf80227039fc79405908f3f"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/zipball/a2580456bda9ff513cf80227039fc79405908f3f",
                "reference": "a2580456bda9ff513cf80227039fc79405908f3f",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "composer/installers": "~1.0",
                "php": ">=5.3.3,<7"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~3.7"
            },
            "type": "silverstripe-module",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "3.x-dev": "3.5.x-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                    "tests/behat/features/bootstrap"
                ]
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "BSD-3-Clause"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "SilverStripe",
                    "homepage": "http://silverstripe.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "The SilverStripe Community",
                    "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org"
                }
            ],
            "description": "The SilverStripe framework",
            "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org",
            "keywords": [
                "framework",
                "silverstripe"
            ],
            "time": "2017-02-20 17:01:16"
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

[***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is a proper tool for manipulating JSON data:

```
jq '.packages[] | select(.name == "silverstripe/framework").version' composer.lock
"3.5.3"
```

Comment: I would prefer not to have to install another 3rd party tool. Also there will be a lot of other packages installed via composer that will have a "version" so wouldn't that command spit out all the versions?

Comment: @ifusion, you have written that you already *extracted the object that contains the version number*. So pipe with `jq` and that will be the needed version

Comment: ah sorry I meant I have extracted the object for the purpose of showing on stackoverflow, there are multiple other packages being installed aswell. Sorry I wasn't more clear, I will edit my original question.